# How to stop Android from switching between Wifi APs automatically?

Tags: wi-fi, 7.0-nougat

I have several WiFi APs for different purposes. One is for printing, one is for smart devices with access to the internet, another for devices with no access to the internet for security concerns, and some others like repeaters, guest APs or streaming devices.
Android 7 always switches between these APs without asking for permission. The only time it asks for confirmation is when switching from WiFi to mobile data.
Using the wrong AP, is not only annoying but has unwanted consequences. Any idea how to stop Android from such nonsense move?

Ps: there is no smart wifi option but wifi plus which is off. 
Ps2: Imagine an app does not have access to the AP or internet it needs or when setting up a device and the WiFi is switched to another AP or connecting to a server with the wrong IP, just because Android decides it wants to use a different WiFi AP.

Comment: is there any chance you have set **Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep** to **Never** (*Wi-Fi->Configure Wi-Fi(Settings icon)->Keep Wi-Fi on during sleep*)? This will turn Wi-Fi off when phone goes to sleep and when it wakes up, it will get connected to any of your available APs at that time based on signal strength.

Comment: The AP's all share the same SSID name?

Answer (score 1):

In Android 7.0, you can actually disable wifi auto-reconnect. Go to Wifi Settings, then tap on one of the AP. Uncheck the Auto-reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue. I have 2 APs and my phone keeps switching between the 2. What I did was made the phone "forget" the APs I DON'T usually use the phone with. Can't connect to an AP you don't have a password for, right? Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, at least I see other people have the same issue. It might benefit some. I do this sometimes but there is no prefered AP and I need to constantly use these APs, and re-establishing the connection with long passwords each time would not be very user-friendly. I'd rather see android sticks to the WiFi AP that it was assigned to.

Comment: My same solution, answerer. A shame there isn't a more user-friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found reference to this command to disable the automatic internet connectivity test, and some reports of it working. I cant test it though. You need a rooted handset. I don't have one and 
currently can't... you first need to su,  then....

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

I've actually put in a technical request to Nikon as my camera suffers the same issue. I can no longer download from it. I'll let you know if I get any joy!